Can't get see-through material for eyes to work
I'm trying to make eyes for my character. I'm working in EEVEE. I've turned on Screen Space Reflections in material settings and its other location, checked the refractions box, switched from opaque to alpha blend, but it still isn't working. I dont know what I'm doing wrong but I'll upload my file.


There's a missing face in your Pupil object:

Since you did not pack the texture into your file, I added a simple red material to see the result. I also added another black material and assigned it to the missing face. Additionally, it's a good idea to use an Environment Texture to achieve better lighting results:

